# Problems with Angular 8 + IVY - Compiler Breaks after template change

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular-ivy

I have a new project on angular 8 and I'm using Ivy, the problem is that when I change anything in the HTML or CSS and save the changes, the app crashes. Then I reset the `ng serve` and everything runs normally. Changing only the TS files does not result in errors.

The main error that I get when doing the changes mentioned above, is "ngIf is not a known attribute of ng-container"

here is my package.json:

```
  "name": "firemaps-v2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.22",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.11",
    "firebase": "^7.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

my ts config:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

my angular.json:

````
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "firemaps-v2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/firemaps-v2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "firemaps-v2:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "firemaps-v2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "firemaps-v2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "firemaps-v2:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "firemaps-v2:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "firemaps-v2"
}```





************* UDPATE

Here is my module:

    ```import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
    import { LoginService } from "./public/login.service";
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    import { HomeComponent } from './public/home/home.component';
    import { MyMatModule } from './material';
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { AngularFireMessagingModule } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { SigninComponent } from './public/login/signin/signin.component';
    import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        SigninComponent,

      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireMessagingModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MyMatModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
      ],
      exports: [MyMatModule],
      providers: [{
        provide: MatDialogRef,
        useValue: {}
      },
      LoginService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [
        SigninComponent
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
    ```
````

Comment: show me the code of where you have used *ngIf. And also you app.module.ts

Comment: There you go, @BinaraThambugala

Comment: Show me your  app.module.ts and the code where you have used ```*ngIf```.

Comment: The *ngIf is not the problem, Always the first use of angular native directives is the problem. Now the problems is on the "async" pipe...

Comment: is this the error you are getting? **Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'**

Comment: Actually the error does not matter... I've turned off AoT and Ivy and all this problems were gone...

Comment: So in fact the question is answered now?

Comment: Yes and no, because I can develop normally, but i cant use ivy... this might be a bug in angular so I'll wati for next version to check this problem again. Thank you for your attention anyways!